# Association between objects and cameras blender python

Tags: python, blender

I have several objects in bpy.data.objects and several cameras in bpy.data.cameras;
The cameras are linked to some of the objects.
How can I know to which of the objects each of the cameras are linked?
I would be so grateful for a piece of code demonstrating that.
Many thanks,
Igal

Answer (score 2):

Blender uses an [object oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) approach to it's data.

The object class contains generic properties such as the location of the object. It then uses it's data property to store object specific data using a class that is specific to the type of object, each of these data types are a subclass of [ID](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.ID.html)

`bpy.data.objects` is a list of the [Object class](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html) instances.

```
>>> type(bpy.data.objects['Camera'])
<class 'bpy_types.Object'>
```

`bpy.data.cameras` is a list of the [Camera class](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Camera.html#bpy.types.Camera) instances that are linked to the camera objects data property.

```
>>> type(bpy.data.cameras['Camera'])
<class 'bpy.types.Camera'>
```

Similarly `bpy.data.meshes` is a list of the [Mesh class](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html) instances that contain mesh object data.

```
>>> type(bpy.data.objects['Cube'])
<class 'bpy_types.Object'>
>>> type(bpy.data.meshes['Cube'])
<class 'bpy_types.Mesh'>
```

When first created, the object and matching data instances use matching names. While the object names are often renamed, the data names are often left alone.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects['Camera']

if obj.type == 'CAMERA':
    print('The',obj.name,'object is a camera.')

if bpy.data.cameras[obj.name] == obj.data:
    print('It uses a camera data object with a matching name')
```